# Ag Grid how to disable column sortable property in edit mode?

Tags: ag-grid-vue

I am new to ag grid.

I have a property name editMode, Any cell change will set it to true. When it is true, I want to set column sortable to false. How to do it ?

I don't want to use setColumnDefs, because it will change other column property that I want keep.

Any help would be grateful.

How to set sortable false when editMode is true, and sortable true when editMode is false ?